# Query is taking long time in spite of indexes

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT id,
    file_name As 'Document',
    ref_number AS 'Ref Number',
    entered_by As 'Entered By',
    created_date As 'Created Date',
    manpower,
    user_path,
    owner_path
FROM t_document_holder
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND incoming_to = 'Criteria'
    AND incoming_from = 'Criteria'
    AND CONTAINS (
        user_path,
        'Criteria'
        )
ORDER BY created_date,
    entered_by
```

**Indexes:**

> id         = Clustered Index
>   ref_number      = Non Clustered
>   entered_by      = Non Clustered Index
>   manpower        = Non Clustered Index
>   user_path and owner_path    = Full Text Search Index
>   incoming_to and incoming_from   = Non Clustered Index

To summarize, most of the columns (all in WHERE condition) are part of an index but still this query is taking 25 seconds to return 527 rows out of total 115,000 rows in table.

Execution Plan[image: Query Execution Plan]

can someone kindly advice that why it is taking so long to return these rows.

Query Execution Plan for Non-Clustered Index

[image]

Comment: Can you hover over the piece of the execution plan that is 59% and paste the details?

Comment: Mangling the column names means the execution plan is meaningless. Why is *IX_document_holder* used instead of a primary key? Is a column named `document_holder` involved? Post the *actual* query, the table and the index definitions

Comment: To optimise this specific query for example, it's better to have a composite index with _both_ column9 and column10 in it. I don't see a sort operator so I guess your clustered index already somehow contains `created_date` in it? Is it any quicker without the `order by`?

Comment: More details for execution plan costing 59% is added.

Original query posted.

Comment: Oh hang on there is a sort operator but it's of no consequence. Anyway.... there are other people better than this at me, but I do see that the estimated number of rows is 1, whereas you say you are returning 527... both are small numbers anyway but that could have something to do with it. Have you rebuilt statistics on this query? Are your criteria actually hard coded in there or are they parameters. (something starting with `@`)

Comment: What is the size of the column `user_path`? Also, not that it should make any difference, I would try using the syntax `...and user_path like '%Criteria%'`. By the way, such query for 115,000 records should take less than a second, even with no indices at all.

Comment: Size of user_path is 400 and datatype is nvarchar. I can't user "LIKE %Criteria%" as it can't take any benefit from non clustered index due to "%" in the beginning of criteria. That was the reason i added this column in "Full Text Search" index and using "Contains" operator.

Comment: how long does it take if you remove the **ORDER BY created_date,
    entered_by** ? I imagine this is causing the problem. You do not have index on created_date

Comment: Removing "ORDER BY" is reducing the time by 3 second..... It is still taking 20-22 Seconds to run the query. :-(

Comment: Have you tried to use CTE !

Comment: I observed again and found that "ORDER BY" clause is making a big difference (in spite of the fact that execution plan is showing its cost only 3%). Even i included the columns in ORDER BY clause in non-clustered indexes but result is still same.

Without ORDER BY result is coming in 2-3 seconds but with it, it takes more than 20 Secs.

What could be the reason ??

Answer (score 1):

After Hours of googling, i found the solution. Solution was to rebuild all indexes on this particular table and it worked like charm. For more details consult this article.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/044316b5-32d7-4264-bde4-1ebfb5633262/order-by-extremely-slow-in-sql-2008-r2?forum=transactsql

Comment: Do you get a different query plan now? How does the "Estimated number of rows" look now? It's possible that just rebuilding statistics may have helped

Comment: We’ll never know, but I’m glad you solved your problem.